# Does Angularjs automatically sanitize all data before rendering to dom?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss, sanitization, ngsanitize

Does Angular sanitize all data when it gets rendered in the DOM automatically? ie, would this be safe:

```
// using 'ngSanitize'
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

// somewhere in controller
$http.get('/data').success(function(userdata) {
    $scope.user.description = userdata.description;
});
```

And then rendering it in the DOM:

```
<span> Hello there, {{ user.description }}</span>
```

or

```
<span ng-model="user.description"></span>
```

This might lead to an **XSS** vulnerability if Angular isn't auto sanitizing the data I'm displaying. If Angular doesn't auto sanitize, what are good way ensure that all data from server is sanitized before rendering?

Answer (score 0):

To get angular to sanitize data, you can use the ng-bind-html directive, which will automatically use $sanitize

```
<div ng-bind-html="hmtlData"></div>
```

More documentation can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: important distinction though between `{{ }}` expressions and `ng-bind-html` is that expressions are treated as text so tags won't render and scripts will be nothing but text also

Comment: @charlietfl What about `<a href="{{ somelink }}">link</a>`? That would be dangerous? Would using `ng-href` sanitize automatically as well?  Are there any other cases that needs attention? The only one I can think of is `ng-bind-html-unsafe` and the one I just mentioned.

Comment: @rublex good question about `ng-href`. There is an $sce.trustAsUrl() method in the `$sce` sanitize docs. My guess...just a guess.. is that `ng-href` may do sanitizing simply because that method exists ...but I don't know for sure